# SSRS matrix group by error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an ssrs matrix with total in rows and months as columns .. something like this .

```
            Jan  Feb    March
Total1
Total2
```

I can choose a month as a parameter and my matrix shows the results for the month and the two months before the current month.

When I choose August :

```
 I can see  June July August
```

When I choose September :

```
I can see July August September
```

But when I choose October

**I see October August September**

My client wants to see it as **August September October**

I don't know the reason for this behavior .But can anyone help me with this ??

I tried doing the sort for the tablix as follows :

```
=(Fields!Month.Value)
```

Month is a number like 1 for Jan, 2 for Feb. I add it as a sorting expression but I dont see any change in the sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was going wrong with my solution .
I was adding the sorting on the "tablix properties" section .
Sorting needs to be added on the "Column group" and not on the "tablix properties" and this did the trick in my case. :-)

Answer (score 2):

according to your data.

August = "8" 
September "9"
October = "10"

it looks to me like you need to convert your month to an integer type, Sort is picking up your month as a string value.

try converting your month field to an integer in your sort expression and then running rerunning the report.

something like:

```
=CInt(Fields!Month.Value)
```